# Custom rails loggers not flushed when stopping passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, passenger

I have several loggers in my rails app which are initialized like this in production:

```
log_file = File.open("#{Rails.root}/log/my_log_#{Rails.env}.log", 'a')
log_file.sync = !Rails.env.production?

LOG = Logger.new(log_file)
```

I use the above as follows:

```
LOG << "my message\n"
```

Note that `log_file.sync` is false in production, because I don't want to write to disk on every message logged. The problem I am noticing is that when I stop my rails apache server (`sudo /etc/init.d/httpd stop`), my `LOG` is not flushed. As a result, I lose messages. Is this expected behavior?

The odd part is that I troubleshooted by using rails console (production) to write a bunch of log messages to said `LOG`. When I closed the rails console, my `LOG` flushed as expected. So this makes me believe there is something wrong with how I am shutting down my rails instance in Passenger.

So how come `LOG` flushes properly in rails console but not in the actual Passenger server? What am I missing?

I am running Rails 3.2.8 and using Apache w/ Passenger 3.0.17.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Passenger 4.0.45 fixed the issue.